# Preg_replace everything after dashes with nothing PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have text that looks like this:

```
$file = "file name-1-03-08-2014_15:56:06.doc";
```

For display purposes, I want to to display just "file name.doc".

So replace everything after the first dash with nothing. I believe I should use preg_replace but am not sure what the pattern would be. Is preg_replace the best function for this?

I can change the file name format to make it easier if necessary.

Comment: Does `file name` stand to change?

Comment: yes the "file name" is different everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this with a regex.

```
preg_replace('/-.*(\..*)$/', '$1', $file);
```

This regular expressions `/-.*/` will match `-` and all characters after it `.*`. The file extension is captured in the parenthetic statement `(\..*)` with the `$` requiring the extension is match at the end of the string. The second argument replaces the matched string with the match extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "file name-1-03-08-2014_15:56:06.doc";
$clean=substr_replace ($file ,'' , strpos($file,'-'),strrpos($file,'.')- strpos($file,'-')  );
echo $clean;
```

No regex solution, just in case...